# What are the Four Noble Families of Soul Society?

Tags: bleach

What are the names of the main Four Families that live in Soul Society?

Is there any information on how they came to be? Or how they became such? And do each of these clans commonly exceeds at a particular area (like the *Shihōin* clan were usually the heads of the Correction Corps, and experts at Kidō and Shunpo)?

Comment: I think Shiba clan is among the 4 noble houses, since Sui Fon refers to it during her fight with Shihouin Youichi. Kasumi-ouji isn't among the 4, as referred by Kuchiki Rukia SSN 9, I think. The remaining house isn't mentioned.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a compiled list of the noble families compiled from the [Bleach Wiki](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Noble_Houses)

They are currently 4 greater noble families, but only 2 have been revealed:

- The [Shihouin](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Shih%C5%8Din_Clan) Clan are tasked with taking care of various treasures and weapons. [Yoruichi](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Yoruichi_Shih%C5%8Din) was formerly the head of this family. The head of this family typically served as the head of the [Onmitsukidou](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Onmitsukid%C5%8D).
- The [Kuchiki](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Kuchiki_Clan) Clan are charged with protecting the history of the Soul Society. [Byakuya Kuchiki](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Byakuya_Kuchiki), Captain of the 6th Division is the head of this family. The Shihouin Shield is used by Juushiro Ukitake (13th Division Captain) and Shunsui Kyouraku (8th Division Captain) to destroy the [Soukyoku](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/S%C5%8Dkyoku).

There used to be a fifth, the [Shiba Clan](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Shiba_Clan), equaling in prestige to the two know greater noble families, but after the death of its most prominent member, the former lieutenant of the 13th Division, [Kaien Shiba](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Kaien_Shiba), the family's prestige seems to have fallen. They seemed to have specialized in fireworks. In Chapter 529, it is revealed that Ichigo's father, Isshin, is from a branch family of the Shiba Clan and former 10th Division Captain.

The [Ryoudoji](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Ry%C5%8Ddoji_Family) were also once a noble family, but they were exiled over 1000 years ago from the current series timeline.

There are also various [lesser noble families](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Noble_Houses#Lower_Noble_Houses) that serve the greater noble families, here are the known ones:

- Feng Clan, served as assassins and executioners for the Shihouin Clan. [Sui Feng](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Su%C3%AC-F%C4%93ng), Captain of the 2nd Division & General Administrator Commander of the Onmitsukido Special Forces, is the head of this Clan.
- Kyouraku Clan, not much is know about this family but the fact the it is quite old and prestigious. [Shunsui Kyouraku](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Shunsui_Ky%C5%8Draku), the captain of the 8th Division is the second son from this family.
- Ukitake Family, is another lower noble family. [Juushirou Ukitake](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/J%C5%ABshir%C5%8D_Ukitake), the captain of the 13th Division is the eldest son of this family.
- Oumaeda Family is a family in service of the Shihou Clan and the [Onmitsukidou](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Onmitsukid%C5%8D) special forces. The current Lieutenant of the 2nd Division and Corps Commander of the Patrol Corps of the Onmitsukidou, [Marechiyo Oumaeda](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Marechiyo_%C5%8Cmaeda) is the eldest son of this Family.
- Kira Family is another lesser noble family, [Izuru Kira](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Izuru_Kira), Lieutenant of the 3rd Division, the a member of this family. His status within the family has not been mentioned.
- [Kasumioji](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Kasumi%C5%8Dji_Clan) Family, they are famous weapon-smiths in Soul society. The members are predominately female.
- Kannogi Family, the appear in to be connected to the Kasumiouji in the anime.

Comment: There is a post by new user mentioning Kasumioji clan. Not sure if it is accurate or not, but if it is, would you please update the answer?

Comment: You might want to add that Kuchiki Byakuya's grandfather was the Captain of the 6th Division before Byakuya. While it is not certain, this gives the same impression as that of 2nd Division in that the head of the Kuchiki Clan is always the Captain of the 6th division.

Answer (score 5):

Based on **[this wiki page](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Noble_Houses)**

> The Noble Houses of Soul Society have an unclear role in the culture, social and governmental aspects of that dimensions existence. The Four Noble Families carry the most weight and appear to have some influence over the governmental institutions (i.e. Central 46 Chambers) and even institutions outside of the government (i.e. Shin'ō Academy). The military (i.e. Gotei 13, Kidō Corps & Onmitsukidō) have no authority to act against a noble family without evidence that their actions are treasonous to Soul Society.

Only two clans were revealed thus fur:

> ### Shihōin Clan
>
> By tradition, the head of the Shihōin family leads the Onmitsukidō.
>   Also known as the Tenshiheisōban (天賜兵装番, House of Godly Gears),
>   they are the Caretakers of the Hōgu (宝具, lit. "Treasure Tool") and
>   Bugu (武具, lit. "War Tool") said to have been bestowed on them by the
>   gods.
>
> ### Kuchiki Clan
>
> There is reason to believe that the captaincy of the 6th Division runs
>   in the Kuchiki family, as at least two members, both of them were
>   family heads, have held the title captain and two other known members
>   have been lieutenant and 3rd seat respectively. Members of the Kuchiki
>   family have been known to wear Kenseikan (牽星箝, lit. "Star-Pulling
>   Insert") in their hair, which symbolizes their nobility as one of Four
>   Noble Families. The Kuchiki family also has a white scarf made by the
>   master weaver, Tsujishirō Kuroemon III. The scarf is made from the
>   Ginpaku Kazahana no Uzuginu (銀白風花の紗, Silks of the Silverwhite
>   Wildflower), a silver-white, windflower light silk, and is a family
>   heirloom that is handed down from generation to generation and is
>   given to each Kuchiki family head. The scarf alone is worth enough to
>   buy ten mansions in the Seireitei. By tradition, the family has
>   been charged with compiling and protecting the history of Soul
>   Society. The family resides in the Kuchiki Family Manor.